# Is OS X's SecRandomCopyBytes fork safe?

Tags: ios, macos, security, prng, security-framework

Many userspace CSPRNG's have an issue where after `fork(2)`, it's possible for the two different processes to return the same stream of random bytes.

From looking at `dtruss`, it's clear that `SecRandomCopyBytes` is, at a minimum, seeding from `/dev/random`, but is it doing so in a way that's safe for use after `fork()`?

With the following source code:

```
#include <Security/Security.h>


int main() {
    uint8_t data[8];
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 8, data);
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 8, data);
    printf("%llu\n", *(uint64_t *)data);
}
```

I get the following from `dtruss` (with irrelevant stuff removed):

```
open("/dev/random\0", 0x0, 0x7FFF900D76F5)       = 3 0
read(0x3, "\b\2029a6\020+\254\356\256\017\3171\222\376T\300\212\017\213\002\034w\3608\203-\214\373\244\177K\177Y\371\033\243Y\020\030*M\3264\265\027\216r\220\002\361\006\262\326\234\336\357F\035\036o\306\216\227\0", 0x40)        = 64 0
read(0x3, "\223??3\263\324\3604\314:+\362c\311\274\326\a_Ga\331\261\022\023\265C\na\211]\356)\0", 0x20)      = 32 0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation is actually CCRandomCopyBytes():

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471/libsecurity_keychain/lib/SecRandom.c

```
int SecRandomCopyBytes(SecRandomRef rnd, size_t count, uint8_t *bytes) {
    if (rnd != kSecRandomDefault)
        return errSecParam;
    return CCRandomCopyBytes(kCCRandomDefault, bytes, count);
}
```

So the actual code is here:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-60049/lib/CommonRandom.c

The comments in the include for CCRandomCopyBytes state that it is fork() safe:

> It is inconvenient to call system random number generators
>   directly. In the simple case of calling /dev/random, the caller
>   has to open the device and close it in addition to managing it
>   while it's open. This module has as its immediate raison d'être
>   the inconvenience of doing this. It manages a file descriptor to
>   /dev/random including the exception processing of what happens
>   in a fork() and exec(). Call CCRandomCopyBytes() and all the
>   fiddly bits are managed for you. Just get on with whatever you
>   were really trying to do.
>   [...]

In my own quick test, the child gets killed when it invokes SecRandomCopyBytes()